# TRANSPOSE COLUMN AS A VARIABLE

Tags: r

I have a `BD` and I want to transpose the columns as variables inside a new column.

This is my `BD`.

```
ID <- c(123,456,789)
NAME <- c('MARY','JOHN','DANIEL')
PECU_05_2021 <- c(64.34,NA,20.59)
SECO_05_2021 <- c(32.17,NA,10.29)
SECJ_05_2021 <- c(NA,NA,20)

BD <- data_frame(ID,NAME,PECU_05_2021,SECO_05_2021,SECJ_05_2021)
```

I want my new BD to have two new columns: `TYPE AND VALUE`

```
ID <- c(123,123,123,456,456,456,789,789,789)
NAME <- c('MARY','MARY','MARY','JOHN','JOHN','JOHN','DANIEL','DANIEL','DANIEL')
TYPE <- c('PECU_05_2021','SECO_05_2021','SECJ_05_2021','PECU_05_2021','SECO_05_2021','SECJ_05_2021','PECU_05_2021','SECO_05_2021','SECJ_05_2021')
VALUE <- c(64.34,32.17,NA,NA,NA,NA,20.59,10.29,20)
BD2 <- data_frame(ID,NAME,TYPE,VALUE)
```

Is it possible to do this transposition including transforming the columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tidyverse solution (since you are using `data_frame`):

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(
  BD, 
  c(PECU_05_2021,SECO_05_2021,SECJ_05_2021), 
  names_to = "TYPE", 
  values_to="VALUE"
)
```